# How to tell Doctrine to save ID

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have some code that has Doctrine annotations for how to save it into the DB.

I have an ID string that has already been generated by the system. I want to tell Doctrine to use the id as the primary key, and also save it into the database when persisting the object.

Currently it seems that Doctrine is just not writing that field.

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO voting_motion (type,
>   name, start_datetime, close_datetime, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["personal_opinion", "Question about
>   food", "2020-07-02 12:00:00", "2020-07-07 13:00:00", "2020-05-27
>   11:16:49", "2020-05-27 11:16:49"]:

i.e. the insert into statement is just not including the ID field.

I thought the GeneratedValue annotation would be the appropriate thing to do here. But it seems not.

How do I tell Doctrine that "this is the primary id, and I do want you to write it when saving the entity"?

This is what my code for the entity with the relevant annotations looks like.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="voting_motion")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class VotingMotion 
{
    /**
     * @Id()
     * @Column(name="id", type="string", unique=true)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private string $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private string $type;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private string $name;

    // ...
    // ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These annotations work fine for me, you don't need to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")` annotation. Also, run `migrations:diff` after changes in the `GeneratedValue` annotation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="guid", unique=true)
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: I'm using doctrine directly. I think your answer assumes I'm using it through symfony? If I try that annotation I get "Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key."
Removing the 'ORM' part seems to get back to my original error, without improvement.

Comment: @Danack before that problem did you use the AUTO strategy?

Comment: @Danack did you change your database schema after changing the strategy from AUTO to NONE?

Comment: yes. the schema is correct, but again, I'm using doctrine by itself and I'm managing the schemas separately to doctrine using phinx. The table looks correct, the only thing is doctrine choosing not to save that property.

Answer (score 0):

I use strategy="UUID" and works fine

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Comment: As per the comment below, I'm using Doctrine by itself, not through Symfony, and those annotations don't work for me.